# Migration in AspNetCore adn EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration, asp.net-identity

my problem is.
When I try to do a Add-Migration, says The EntityFramework is not installed.
But, first i'am using EntityFrameworkCore, and he is installed.
I Try  download the entityFramework but doesn't resolved, he says is a null instance.

I reinstall the EntityFrameworkCore Too

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall everything and close and open the visual studio.